# Does LVS_EX_FULLROWSELECT have any compatibility issues with other styles?

Tags: c++, listview, mfc, clistctrl, common-controls

I am trying to set the LVS_EX_FULLROWSELECT style on my grid list control as I want full row selection. However apparently it doesn't have any effect. Since I am using a number of other styles as well, I am wondering if LVS_EX_FULLROWSELECT has any compatibility issues with other styles. Anyone? Following are the styles I am setting.

Initially following styles are set on base list control class:

```
WS_CHILD|WS_BORDER|LVS_REPORT|LVS_SHOWSELALWAYS|LVS_SINGLESEL
```

Then I try to set additional styles in the derived grid list control class:

```
ListView_SetExtendedListViewStyleEx(sysId(), 0, LVS_EX_GRIDLINES | LVS_OWNERDATA | LVS_EX_FULLROWSELECT);
```

Answer (score 4):

The second parameter is a mask, so you need:

```
ListView_SetExtendedListViewStyleEx(m_hWnd, LVS_EX_GRIDLINES | LVS_OWNERDATA | LVS_EX_FULLROWSELECT, LVS_EX_GRIDLINES | LVS_OWNERDATA | LVS_EX_FULLROWSELECT);
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried but it didn't work. By the way isn't a 0 in second parameter means match everything. At least this is what documentation says.

Answer (score 2):

You need to send the LVM_`SETEXTENDEDLISTVIEWSTYLE` message to the control and specify the `LVS_EX_FULLROWSELECT` extended style (source: [MS Support](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/230049)).

**Edit:**

Check the example. There is

```
ListView_SetExtendedListViewStyle(m_hWnd, ListView_GetExtendedListViewStyle(m_hWnd), VS_EX_FULLROWSELECT);
```

Try using `ListView_GetExtendedListViewStyle(sysId())` instead of `0`. BTW - does this `sysId()` of yours really retrieve the window handle? The name sounds somewhat different.

Cheers.

Comment: Thank but this is what I am doing. The ListView_SetExtendedListViewStyleEx macro calls the LVM_SETEXTENDEDLISTVIEWSTYLE behind the scene. And I already have LVS_EX_FULLROWSELECT in the call. But it is not working, that's why I thought LVS_EX_FULLROWSELECT style may have compatibility issues with other styles I am using.

Comment: I've edited my answer to give you more detailed hint. Hope it helps.

Comment: It still doesn't work. It seems LVM_SETEXTENDEDLISTVIEWSTYLE is conflicting with some of the other styles I am setting. Yes sysId() does retrieve the window handle. Thanks anyway.